# BlazeDS: where is log file stored on server?

Tags: linux, apache-flex, glassfish, blazeds

If I have the following in my `services-config.xml` file for setting up BlazeDS log file on a linux server, where does it save the log file? Or, does the output show up by default in Flash Builder 4.6 (e.g. no further info in log file)?

I've been trying to figure this out reading

http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=services_logging_3.html

but haven't been able to figure it out. I must be missing something obvious. Any advice appreciated.

```
<logging>
    <target class="flex.messaging.log.ConsoleTarget" level="Error">
        <properties>
            <prefix>[BlazeDS] </prefix>
            <includeDate>true</includeDate>
            <includeTime>true</includeTime>
            <includeLevel>true</includeLevel>
            <includeCategory>true</includeCategory>
        </properties>
        <filters>
            <pattern>Endpoint.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Service.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Configuration</pattern>
        </filters>
    </target>
</logging>
```

Is there a way I can specify a location for the log file to be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the link you provided:

> **Setting the logging target**
>
> By default, the server writes log messages to System.out. In the class
>   attribute of the target element, you can specify
>   flex.messaging.log.ConsoleTarget (default) to log messages to the
>   standard output, **or the `flex.messaging.log.ServletLogTarget` to log
>   messages to the default logging mechanism for servlets for your
>   application server.**

So you either have to configure logging in your application server (for Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) or use something like log4j in your servlet.

**services-config.xml** should then look something like this:

```
<target class="flex.messaging.log.ServletLogTarget" level="warn">
        <properties>
            <prefix>[BlazeDS] </prefix>
            <includeDate>true</includeDate>
            <includeTime>true</includeTime>
            <includeLevel>true</includeLevel>
            <includeCategory>true</includeCategory>
        </properties>
        <filters>
            <pattern>Endpoint.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Service.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Message.*</pattern>
            <pattern>DataService.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Configuration</pattern>
        </filters>
    </target>
</logging>
```

---

Sidenote: We use log4j and [spring-flex](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex), which provides `org.springframework.flex.core.CommonsLoggingTarget` to handle BlazeDS output.

**services-config.xml**

```
<logging>
    <target class="org.springframework.flex.core.CommonsLoggingTarget" level="debug">
        <properties>
            <categoryPrefix>blazeds</categoryPrefix>
        </properties>
    </target>
</logging>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.appender.myAppLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppLog.File=${catalina.base}/logs/myAppLog.txt

log4j.appender.myBlazeLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myBlazeLog.File=${catalina.base}/logs/myBlazeLog.txt

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,myAppLog
log4j.logger.blazeds=ALL,myBlazeLog
```

Comment: Thanks dgesang, I'm using GlassFish, so if I change my application's services-config.xml file as shown above to `class="flex.messaging.log.ServletLogTarget"`, then will GlassFish send it's output to its server log automatically? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gixud.html

Comment: It should, yes, but I remember having a hard time setting it up and eventually went for the spring-flex implementation above.